# Netbeans 7 - Won't navigate to declaration with multiple projects registered

Tags: php, netbeans

I've been battling this demon for a while (at least since about 6.8) and I'm wondering if any kind soul here has found similar issue and resolved it.  I have about 12 PHP projects registered in my Netbeans IDE.  Works great, although it can take a while to open up from startup.  However my biggest issue is that if I have functions, methods, classes, etc. referenced in my code and I select (for example) a function, I want it to open up the PHP code module that contains that declaration, and it used to do this.

But as soon as I added a 2nd project to my IDE, it no longer wants to play.  Just sits there like nothing was requested.  So I have to manually navigate to the code each time.  Its getting tiresome, and I'm sure I can't be the only one to have found this.

Has anyone found this and found a resolution to it?  I'd be happy if it only navigates without the 'Main Project' if that would work, but even if I set the project that way it refuses to go looking for the declaration.

All help greatly appreciated.

P.S.  I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 on my desktop rig.  Not sure if that has anything to do with this though.   And its the PHP personality in Netbeans.

Comment: Works for me. I opened two projects and go to worked in both main and the other project. `Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0 (Build 201104080000)`

Comment: Hmmm.... Interesting.  Not sure if this makes any difference, but I'm running Ubuntu here.  Also if the same function appears in multiple projects, does it still let you navigate to the local one?

Comment: Just checked. Opened a copy of main project and it still works. Finds the classes and functions in correct folders. I am running NB on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with some reflection API bug in NetBeans. The solution is simple: export your projects and uninstall NetBeans, then download the latest IDE and import your project. This should work. If doesn’t, then update Java and check. If it still doesn’t work then close all projects and restart the IDE, then load all projects one by one and see in which it works and in which it doesn&rquo;t. If you find problems with a specific project, submit your bug at netbeans.org or use the inbuilt system in the IDE itself for submitting bugs in Options.

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct.  I did find, however, that I can do this with NB 7 if I hold down CTRL and mouse over the function then click on it.  The keyboard shortcut (CTRL-B) isn't working per your explanation, but the mouse click on it is working.  Thanks!

Comment: see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369807/netbeans-php-go-to-declaration-issue

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with Netbeans 12 & Java. Turned out that the warning about not being able to install the nb-javac plugin when I started it up actually was important. After configuring the proxy to get through my company network I was able to install the plugin and get the Navigation features working.

Answer (score 1):

I continue to have similar problems with an 8.1 installation. Best guess so far is a large project may have unresolved files that got deleted or renamed on disk, and this could be breaking the find function for all routines in that project.  Look at the last 50 lines or so in the `~/.netbeans/8.1/var/log/messages.log` file, and see if it's complaining about files not found.  Also try deleting directory `~/.cache/netbeans/8.1`, sometimes that does the trick.

Comment: Removing `~/.cache/netbeans` helped. Netbeans rebuilded dictionaries. God bless to SSD disks.