# "Go to declaration" does not work in Netbeans PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, code-navigation

Some of my defined classes are not loaded by the IDE when I call <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, Go to declaration, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click.

I'm using Windows 7, NetBeans, PHP 7.0.1

My classes are defined under `<project-root>/foloder00/folder01/folder02/MyClass.php`

I call `MyClass` `<project-root>/index.php`

Do you know what the problem is? And the workaround?

Comment: Does it find the class when using ctrl+click?

Comment: Sometimes clearing the cache in %USERPROFILE%\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache folder helps.

Comment: Note that the suggestion by @meze will likely cause a rescan of your project, which may take some time.

Comment: Could you give us the path to the file where it won't load the definition, the path to the definition, and where your project root is at?  We need all that to diagnose this.

Comment: This happens to me after some time working within a project. I simply delete the nbproject folder and create the project once again. It works, but it's not a very cool solution. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Spooner ctrl-click doesn't work either

Comment: @Levi The path where definition doesn't work is at `<project-root>`. The path for the definition is in my question.

Comment: @Boo I tried to re-create the `nbproject` too - it didn't work though

Comment: @meze `Sometimes` is not enough for me :) Thank you

Comment: @NamGiVU FYI, the comment that you left for me didn't show up in my user page. I'm going to assume the the reason it didn't is because you didn't use my full username.

Comment: @JonathanSpooner Thank you! I know it for now.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884846/netbeans-7-wont-navigate-to-declaration-with-multiple-projects-registered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a workaround for myself. Share with you in case you might need it like me.

Project Property - Include Path - Add the location of the containing folder where it doesn't work/isn't loaded.

Cheers

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you add an include path folder or remove the project, it causes rebuilding cache, so 99% go to declartion will stop working in the future again :)

Comment: delete the cache folder is the only way

Answer (score 32):

As suggested by Nam, it is cache related. So another approach could be to delete the cache:

1. Close NetBeans
2. Delete cache folder (by default, on Linux it is located in `/home/USER/.cache/netbeans`)
3. Open the project and wait for the `scanning project` task to finish.

Comment: Still an issue with NetBeans 8.0.2. Cache location is shown at "Help-> About"

Comment: I'm using IE8.2 can I delete all everthing in cach fold?

Comment: Windows.....  User directory: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2.............
Cache directory: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2

Comment: deleted cache, rescanned projects, problem persists

Answer (score 16):

Deleting the Netbeans cache and letting Netbeans rebuild the cache after start fixes the 'go to declaration' issue, as suggested by others.

On Windows 7 with Netbeans 8.0 the path to the cache is

c:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\

Answer (score 4):

For Linux users to delete cache:

```
rm -fR /home/[user]/.cache/[netbeans_version]
```

Then restart NetBeans.

Comment: For me, it was: rm -rf /home/*user*/.cache/netbeans/*version*/ (no underline at the end)

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools->Options-> click on PHP Icon on top -> General tab -> find "Global include path" -> Add Folder ->

if(onLinux) { choose /var/www; } if(onWindows) { choose c:\path_to_htdocs or whatever; }

Ah, too much programming for today.. :)

For me, this repaired autocompletion and ctrl+click on method call.

Comment: In Netbeans (my version is 12.1): Tools->Options->PHP Icon->General and add the project folder in "Global include path".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Netbeans 8.0.2.

Clearing the cache had no effect then I noticed the syntax coloring was not working either.  The issue was the abbreviated comment tag was not recognized `<?` and when I changed it to `<?php` then syntax coloring and Ctrl-B worked again.

Comment: You need to enable the *Allow short tags (<?)* option in the project properties.

Comment: Do this : Go to Tools->Options-> click on PHP Icon on top -> General tab -> find "Global include path" -> Add Folder -> Apply (Like TomoMiha said)

Comment: So strange... changing my tags from <?php to <? and back to <?php fixed all my issues with intellisense and goto definition...

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue deleting the nbproject directory on my project.

After deleteting this directory, just restart your ide.
It'll start going to declarations, functions and classes again.

Answer (score 1):

If You working with **Drupal** in NetBeans and have the same ctrl+click (Go to declaration) issue:

1. Add/associate ***.module, *.inc** extensions as **text/x-php5** files
   (*NetBeans > Options > Miscellaneous > Files*).
2. Close NetBeans.
3. Clear NetBeans cache (as described above).
4. Open the project and wait for the scanning project task to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the trick.  I had been battling "go to declaration" problems since upgrading to Netbeans 8, and was *this close* to moving to another IDE.  Oddly enough the autocomplete wasn't affected.  My guess is the improved autocomplete for class and interface inheritance added in the 8.x branch gummed up the works somehow, as manually specifying the file types wasn't necessary in 7.x.

Answer (score 1):

In windows system, we cannot see the AppData folder directly.
So we need to browse the below given path to delete the Netbeans cache:
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\NetBeans
Delete the cache folder.
If it still doesn't work then delete the sub-folders inside 
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\var
Then reopen your netbeans and let it scan projects.

Comment: Or just type/paste `%AppData%` in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on Mac, I solved it by deleting netbeans cache directory:

- Close netbeans, Find and delete Cache directory of netbeans, it will solve your
  problem:
- Replace '7.1.2' with your installed version of Netbeans, in directory paths given below.

**MAC:**
Remove following directory:

```
 ~/.netbeans/7.1.2/var/cache/
```

command:rm -rf ~/.netbeans/7.1.2/var/cache/
[image]

**Windows XP:**
Remove following directory:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\(user)\.netbeans\7.1.2\var\cache
```

**Windows Vista / 7:**
Remove following directory:

```
C:\Users\(user)\.netbeans\7.1.2\var\cache
```

**Linux:**
Remove following directory:

```
.netbeans/7.1.2/var/cache
```

**LINK:**[Here is detailed discussion about the issue](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/clear-your-cache-in-netbeans/)

Answer (score 0):

For me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> does not work when I choose 'Put NetBeans metadata into a separate directory' when doing PHP in Netbeans 7.3.1 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on ubuntu 16.04 and I solved it doing what was written [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256166)

- Edit `netbeans.conf` (on Ubuntu 16.04 `/etc/netbeans.conf`)
- Add the `--cp:p /usr/share/java/jcodings.jar` to `netbeans_default_options`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved  by installing JRE

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting the Cache didn't work.  Deleting and recreating the project did.

For what it's worth, my Cache directory lives here:

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

I'm using NetBeans 8.1 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleting the Cache folder did not work.

Then i realized that the source files that i have opened in NetBeans, were not included as part of a project. So i went ahead and selected: **File > Open Project > chose the original project folder** in my htdocs (XAMPP).

Then the declaration mapping worked like a charm. Hope it helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in *Netbeans 11.0*.
My OS is *Ubuntu 18.04*.
I solved the issue by clearing the cache of netbeans.
Cache path of Netbeans 11 is

**/home/USER/snap/netbeans/common/cache/11.0**

Answer (score 0):

> Go to Tools->Options-> click on PHP Icon on top -> General tab -> find
>   "Global include path" -> Add Folder -> .

This worked for me on `netbeans 11` also

Answer (score 0):

I am with netbeans 8.2.
My project was recognized by netbeans as a nodejs project, and my right click->properties looked different:
[netbeans -> nodejs project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiCKj.jpg)

I changed it to a php project, and ctrl+click (go to declaration) started to work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

OS Linux Centos 7
Netbeans 8.0.2
Problem solved Project Properties / Code Assistance
Check property Extra Source Files

Answer (score -1):

For me nothing worked. I was not able to go to some functions of my models whereas some others worked well. I realize that changing the function name was the solution : i had the same function name in other models, and netbeans can't find the good one (well asking would be the best solution). After modification with a unique function name, all is ok