# Netbeans 7.2 Ctrl + Click doesn't work

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

Fresh install of Netbeans 7.2 for PHP (literally 5 mins old) never installed on this system before.

Ctrl+Click fails when clicking on the parent class `Class Foo extends Bar` also namespaced classes.

Only local methods are found when ctrl + clicking

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369807/netbeans-php-go-to-declaration-issue) didn't help me either. All code is contained in one directory.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8369807/369317

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is facing the same problem with Netbeans 12 & Java, then check if you have **nb-javac plugin** installed or not!

Installing **nb-javac** plugin solved the issue for me in Netbeans 12.3.

To check/ install plugin, you can go to Tools> Plugin> Search.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a fresh install, is the project cache finished building?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click:

```
Put selection on a method > Ctrl-B
```

Answer (score 0):

**in windows 7 :** first close your netbeans then you should  go to the **C:\Users{YourUserName}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.2**  and delete all the content of **7.2 folder** .now open your netbeans.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the project for properties, then chose "Code Assistance", then select the "PHP Code Assistance", everything will get ok!

Comment: I can't see "Code Assistance" property in project settings. There is Tools->Options->Editor->Code Completion though